# Replace "" (empty string) to null using Spark dataframe.write method while writing to csv

Tags: scala, apache-spark

While writing a spark dataframe using write method to a csv file, the csv file is getting populated as "" for null strings

```
101|abc|""|555
102|""|xyz|743
```

Using the below code:

```scala
dataFrame
  .coalesce(16)
  .write
  .format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
  .option("nullValue", null)
  .option("emptyValue", null)
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .save(path)
```

Expected output:

```
101|abc|null|555
102|null|xyz|743
```

Spark version 3.2 and Scala version 2.1

Comment: if you want null to be printed out as "null", then you need to map all null values to the string "null" somewhere (maybe in .option?)

Comment: There's only strings in CSV format, there's no such thing as `null`. The value for `nullValue` should be a string.

Comment: You can drop everything except `option("nullValue", null)`. So, what happens when you replace this with `option("nullValue", "null")`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in the option definition; the option values should be specified as String `"null"` instead of `null`, like:

```scala
dataFrame.coalesce(16).write.format("csv")
.option("delimiter", "|")
.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
.option("nullValue", "null")
.option("emptyValue", "null")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(path)
```

Comment: In that case if I query my table like "Select * from mytable where col1 is null" will return no results.

Comment: What table? You're writing a CSV and CSV only has string types, `null` doesn't exist in CSV.

Comment: What is the definitin (DLL) of `mytable`? What is the `.csv` file's contents after applying @Pritish's advice?

Comment: Instead of "null", "\u0000" can be used. It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
dataFrame.coalesce(16).write.format("csv")
.option("delimiter", "|")
.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
.option("nullValue", "\u0000")
.option("emptyValue", "\u0000")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(path)
```

This solved the issue.